# integrating gamma pdf over fixed limits

Tags: integration, definite-integrals, improper-integrals, gamma-function, gamma-distribution

I am trying to solve $\int \limits _u^v x^{m-1}e^{-x} dx$.  I checked table of integrals too but there is no direct solution for this, any help?

Comment: The function $x^\alpha e^{-x}$ does not have an elementary antiderivative. Try using taylor series or integration by parts

Comment: If you have $u = x$ or $v = x$, you can express the antiderivative using the lower or upper incomplete gamma functions. Otherwise, there will not be an elementary antiderivative.

Answer (score 2):

In terms of the [lower incomplete gamma function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Incomplete_gamma_function#Lower_incomplete_Gamma_function), defined by
$$\gamma(a,x) = \int_0^x t^{a - 1} e^{-t} \, dt, \quad a > 0,$$
your integral can be rewritten as

$$\int_u^v x^{m - 1} e^{-x} \, dx = \int_0^v x^{m - 1} e^{-x} \, dx - \int_0^u x^{m - 1} e^{-x} \, dx = \gamma (m,v) - \gamma (m,u), \quad m > 0.$$

Comment: I tried this on software but the answer obtained from integral doesnt match with the answer obtained by gamma function

Answer (score 1):

Musn't have been a very comprehensive  table-of-integrals you consulted. This kind of integral is one of the most thoroughly studied, being *canonised* as the *incomplete gamma-function* ... and is even considered to be *almost* an elementary function!